# Weird behavior with exceptions thrown from std::async, in MSVC 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I just upgrade from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015, and I'm running into a bunch of issues with things that used to work in 2013, but which do not in 2015.

For example, here's one that has me stumped. I created a test-case out of the original code.

Basically, the code runs some operations in a thread, via std::async(). Within the thread, exceptions might be thrown (A), which should be placed in the future object returned by std::async(). The weird thing is that in (B), the destructor of Ex is called, but the object is still thrown aftewards. In the try-block, when the ex (D) variable leaves the score, if 'mInts' vector (X) is a member, the program would crash. If I leave 'mInts' commented out, as below, I still get weird behavior. For example, this is what's printed with the code below: notice how the constructor is called one, but the destructor is called 4 times:

Output:

```
constructor    
destructor   
before exception   
after exception  
destructor   
has exception   
destructor   
destructor
```

Code:

```
using FutureList = std::vector<std::future<void>>;

struct Ex {
  Ex() {
    std::cout << "constructor\n";
  }

  Ex(const Ex&) = delete;
  Ex(Ex&&) {
    std::cout << "move constructor";
  }

 ~Ex() {
    std::cout << "destructor\n";
  }

  void operator=(const Ex&) {
    std::cout << "assign\n";
  }

// std::vector<int> mInts; (X)
};


TEST(Explore, Test1) {
  FutureList futures;

  futures.push_back(
    std::async(std::launch::async, []() {           
        throw Ex();     // (A)
    }));


  std::exception_ptr ex;
  for (auto& i : futures) {
    try {
        i.get(); // (B)
        std::cout << "Doesn't get here.\n";
    }
    catch (...) { // (C)
        std::cout << "before exception\n";
        ex = std::current_exception();    // (D)
        std::cout << "after exception\n";
    }
  }

  if (ex) {
    std::cout << "has exception\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: How weird. I just remarked on another question, about the VC++ 6.0 bug where it called destructor of exception object twice. Anyway, do you get the same discrepancy between constructor and destructor calls, now that you've allowed for VC++'s incorrect calls of copy constructor?

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf: No discrepancy now. The issue with the printout was because there was no printing in the copy constructor. I added some, and the constructor/destructor count matched.

Comment: It would be nice if you would write up your finding as an answer to your question, and accept it. That's entirely OK, if you wonder. It helps others and gives you some sorely needed reputation points. ;-)

Comment: Please abstract away this `TEST` macro and add a `main` function, so that we can reproduce your problem ourselves as-is. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @bogdan - You go ahead, report it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some information I found recently. I'll hold off filing a bug for now; we'll see how MSVC handles things once the Standard wording is adjusted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, MSVC doesn't call the copy constructor in your example. There's no code to call; the function is deleted. It does something worse: it treats the class as being trivially copyable and does a `memcpy` on the object. That's the reason for the crash when you have a member of type `std::vector<int>`.

The problem is not directly related to `std::async`. It's caused by the implementation of `std::exception_ptr`. The shared state of a `std::future` uses an `exception_ptr` to store an exception, so using a `future` in the context of exceptions will trigger the problem. The issue can otherwise be reproduced when using only `std::current_exception()`, which involves a copy in VC 14's standard library implementation (the Standard allows that).

The problem is with the implementation of `__ExceptionPtr::_CallCopyCtor` in `crt/src/stl/excptptr.cpp`. It essentially does a test that goes like "Is there a copy constructor? No? Great, we can do a `memcpy` then!".

Another problem is that the test ignores access specifiers. If you provide a copy constructor but make it `private`, it will be called.

The test is done at runtime, so no chance for a compile-time error, and, unfortunately, that's the only way to do it: there is no general compile-time test that will tell what type of exception object an `std::exception_ptr` will point to in all cases.

The proposed resolution for [Core issue 1863](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1863) aims to avoid this problem by requiring that

> [...] the constructor selected for a copy-initialization considering the thrown object as an lvalue shall be non-deleted and accessible. [...]

The issue is in `Ready` status, which is one step away from adoption.

So, while this is definitely a problem with MSVC, it's also related to an open issue in the Standard. For now, it looks like a good idea to provide a copy constructor for exception objects, even if the Standard doesn't require it (yet).

---

Update: The resolution for issue 1863 has been adopted into the N4567 working draft, so compilers implementing the change are required to reject the code if a suitable constructor is not available.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that MSVC 2015 still calls the copy constructor, even though it's marked deleted. To get around this issue, I defined the copy constructor.

The issue with the printout was because there was no printing in the copy constructor. I added some, and the constructor/destructor count matched.

Still, MSVC 2015 shouldn't be calling the copy-constructor if it's marked deleted. If it must be called, then it should issue an error.